# How to fix "FUNCTION doesnt exist" error in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

im writing a query for **total sales of each product for each salesman who had sales on more than 1 product** on mySQL

Tables are :

product(Product_id,Product_name,price) ,

salesman(Salesman_id,Salesman_name),

sales(Sales_id,Salesman_id,Product_id,quantity)

So far, i've tried this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(sales.Product_id), Salesman_name, quantity 
FROM sales, product, salesman
WHERE sales.Product_id=product.Product_id and sales.Salesman_id=salesman.Salesman_id
GROUP BY (sales.Salesman_id)
HAING COUNT (sales.Product_id)>1
```

I couldnt find how to fix the error "sales.count doesnt exist", error code: 1630

Comment: Not sure if this is in your live code, but there's a typo: `HAING` > `HAVING`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the space in `HAVING` clause between `COUNT` and `(`

Try this:

```
HAVING COUNT(sales.Product_id)>1
```

Comment: `having`........

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this query fits better with your requirements:

```
  select s.Salesman_id,sm.Salesman_name,sum(Quantity) as TotalSales
  from sales s
    join product p
      on s.Product_id=p.Product_id
    join salesman sm
      on sm.Salesman_id=s.Salesman_id
  group by s.Salesman_id, sm.Salesman_name
  having count(p.Product_id)>1
```

Comment: thank you, but it also gives an error "unknown columns, s.Salesman_name in field list"

Comment: Yes, there was an error in the alias. It's fixed.

Comment: it only returns the most selled product sold by a salesman, i want to return every product sold by each salesman. do you know how to fix it?